# How to repeat an operation on a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I want to have a list of 4-letters, then I want to pick two elements of it randomly, merge them together, and add it as a new element to the original list. This way I make a new list. Now I want to repeat the same procedure from the new list, meaning taking two elements from the new list randomly merge them together and make a new list again. So far I did the first step:

```
import random
num = 2
aList = ['A','B','C','D']
newList = []
newList+=random.sample(aList, num)
L = [''.join(newList[0:2])]+aList
print(L)
```

I wonder how to repeat the procedure say 5 more times.

Comment: Use a for loop? https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Comment: What would your expected output look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By creating a function:

```
import random

def randMerge(l:list, count:int) -> list:
    """Returns the input list expanded by a joined element consisting of
    count elements from itself (no repeats allowed)"""
    return l + [''.join(random.sample(l,k=count))]
```

and calling it repeatedly:

```
num = 2
aList = ['A','B','C','D']
newList = aList[:]
for _ in range(6):
    print(newList)
    newList = randMerge(newList,num)
print(newList)
```

Output:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'DC']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'DC', 'ADC']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'DC', 'ADC', 'CD']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'DC', 'ADC', 'CD', 'CDA']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'DC', 'ADC', 'CD', 'CDA', 'CDC']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'DC', 'ADC', 'CD', 'CDA', 'CDC', 'ADCCDC']
```

Comment: @William [How does accepting answers work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/377931)  - accepting an answer is **not** mandatory, just your way of saying "this one helped me the most" - upvotes (although you do not yet see them as you do not have enough rep yet) is a way of also saying "this was helpfull". Any upvote you do now, will come into effect if you ever reach enough rep to be allowed to upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out

```
import random
aList = ['A','B','C','D']
for i in range(5): aList.append(''.join(random.sample(aList, num)))
print(aList)
```

Answer (score 1):

Mya be you can create a method :

```
import random
num = 2
aList = ['A','B','C','D']
def randomizeList(list):
    newList = []
    newList+=random.sample(list, num)
    L = [''.join(newList[0:2])]+list
    return L
```

Now u call this method as many times as you want:

```
list = randomizeList(randomizeList(randomizeList(randomizeList(aList))))
```

or

```
list1 = randomizeList(aList)
list2 = randomizeList(list1)
list3 = randomizeList(list2)
```

and ......

Comment: Do not use `list` `set` `dict` etc as variable names - they shadow the build-ins

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

```
     import random
     def randomoperation():
         num = 2
         aList = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
         newList = []
         newList += random.sample(aList, num)
         L = [''.join(newList[0:2])]+aList
         return L
     for i in range(5):
         print randomoperation()
```