# Power set manipulation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, powerset

I am manipulating a set, so if you have a set(aka:list) of n distinctive elements, then you have 2^n subset. Here I show how:

```
def powerset(s):
    x = len(s)
    masks = [1 << i for i in range(x)]
    for i in range(1 << x):
        yield [ss for mask, ss in zip(masks, s) if i & mask]

l = list(powerset(["A", "B"]))
print(l)
```

which gives:

```
[[], ['A'], ['B'], ['A', 'B']]
```

Now how can take the above list eliminate the empty list, and merge the last element such that it becomes:

```
['A', 'B', 'AB']
```

I want to repeat this procedure 5 times, taking final output and write its sublist, eliminate the empty list and merge those elements that they fall into the same sublist.

Comment: First lists, now sets .... why? [YourOtherQuestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49669856/how-to-repeat-an-operation-on-a-list)

Comment: There is a `itertools` - recipes for powersets:  https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes that you can modidy to exclude the empty set. as well as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035595/powersets-in-python-using-itertools

Comment: "..set(aka:list)"?  `Set` and `list` are different in python.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Thanks Patrick indeed I needed to distinguish between the two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the empty set, just start your loop with `1` instead of `0`, then `''.join`:

```
def powerset(s):
    x = len(s)
    masks = [1 << i for i in range(x)]
    for i in range(1, 1 << x):
        yield ''.join(ss for mask, ss in zip(masks, s) if i & mask)
```

If you want to repeat this, i.e. get the powerset of the powerset of the original list, just feed the result back into the function in a loop:

```
lst = ["A", "B"]
for _ in range(5):
    lst = list(powerset(lst))
    print(lst)
```

Having said that, it might make more sense to do this filtering and joining as a post-processing step, as in @L3viathan's answer, as a true `powerset` function should neither omit nor modify results.

Answer (score 1):

First, filter out the falsy (empty) elements, then join the elements of the remaining elements:

```
>>> l = [[], ['A'], ['B'], ['A', 'B']]
>>> list(map(''.join, filter(bool, l)))
['A', 'B', 'AB']
```

Equivalent list-comprehensiony way:

```
>>> l = [[], ['A'], ['B'], ['A', 'B']]
>>> [''.join(e) for e in l if e]
['A', 'B', 'AB']
```

---

To do this five times, do it five times:

```
start = ["A", "B"]
for _ in range(5):
    start = [''.join(e) for e in powerset(start) if e]
```

Comment: Thanks how can I take the last list meaning ['A', 'B', 'AB'] and do the same procedure on it now? I want to know how to make a for loop inside. So now that I have ['A', 'B', 'AB'] I can have 8 sublist and i want to do the same as before namely eliminate the empty list and merge the ones that are in one sublist

Comment: @tobias_k We start by the set ["A","B"] we write the subset after eliminating the empty subset and merging the the elements, so [[], ['A'], ['B'], ['A', 'B']] becomes ['A', 'B', 'AB'], Now I want to take ['A', 'B', 'AB'] and write its subsets in similar manner. And repeat the procedure 5 times

Comment: @William Added how to repeat it.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [[], ['A'], ['B'], ['A', 'B']]
list(filter(None,map(lambda x:''.join(x) if x else None, data)))
>>>['A', 'B', 'AB']
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like a `flatmap`?

```
from itertools import chain, imap

def flatmap(f, items):
        return chain.from_iterable(imap(f, items))

>>> list(flatmap(lambda x: x, [[], ['A'], ['B'], ['A', 'B']]))
['A', 'B', 'A', 'B']
```

Answer (score 0):

Was this what you were looking for:

```
def powerset(s):
    x = len(s)
    masks = [1 << i for i in range(x)]
    for i in range(1 << x):
        item = ''.join([ss for mask, ss in zip(masks, s) if i & mask])
        if item:
            yield item
l = list(powerset(["A", "B", "C"]))
print(l) 
#['A', 'B', 'AB', 'C', 'AC', 'BC', 'ABC']
```

I introduced `C` as it obviously works with `A` and `B`.

Comment: Thanks how can I take the last list meaning ['A', 'B', 'AB'] and do the same procedure on it now? I want to know how to make a for loop inside. So now that I have ['A', 'B', 'AB'] I can have 8 sublist and i want to do the same as before namely eliminate the empty list and merge the ones that are in one sublist